# Why don't I have to regenerate keys when I change a user's password?

Tags: users, key-authentication, passwd

We have a Linux box (Ubuntu, but that shouldn't matter), say, `somemachine.example.com`, and a user that has access to that machine, `someuser`.

I can SSH into that machine either by explicitly provided a password for `someuser` like so:

```
ssh someuser@somemachine.example.com
Password: *****
```

...or by providing a PEM file (public key):

```
ssh -i ~/path/to/somemachine.pem someuser@somemachine.example.com
```

Today I had to change the password for `someuser` on that box (using the `passwd` command), and was a little surprised to learn that I didn't have to also regenerate new keypairs (thus, new PEM file) for that user as well.

I'm wondering: why? Is there simply no connection between `someuser`'s password and the public/private key? If so, does Linux maintain, for each user, a set of *credentials*, which could either be passwords or public keys? How does Linux associate keys and passwords with particular users?

Comment: To summarize: an ssh keys is a _different_ credential to a password; changing one doesn't change the other.  There can be multiple ssh keys authorized for an account.  See https://www.sweharris.org/post/2016-09-05-sshkeys/ for some of the problems with ssh key management

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ssh` keys and login-passwords are stored in separate locations on virtually any Unix-like system.  There's no reason why (aside from 30 years of history *preceding* `ssh`) the two couldn't have used the same storage.  But what we have now is separate, with scattered attempts to store the collection of credentials in key-managers.

Typically a user's `ssh` information is in **`$HOME/.ssh`**, while the logon information is in **`/etc/passwd`**, **`/etc/shadow`/**, **`/etc/group`** and **`/etc/gshadow`**.

A key manager ***could*** combine those, by providing passwords (or the analogous information) as needed.  But that's the exception rather than the rule.

Not to recommend it one way or the other, I worked with *SnareWorks* a while back.  If you google on that, it appeared on the scene around 2000.  That collected the credentials for various applications (or remote systems) and associated the collection with a user.

Answer (score 1):

SSH keys are not linked you the users password at all, they are two completely separate authentication mechanisms. When ssh keys are used sshd looks in `$HOME/.ssh/authorized_keys` or `$HOME/.ssh/authorized_keys2` for public keys to try. It these public keys with the private key on the client and some [crypt magic](https://medium.com/@vrypan/explaining-public-key-cryptography-to-non-geeks-f0994b3c2d5#.uqtj9acql) to authenticate the user.

When ssh uses password auth, it uses PAM to do the authentication. PAM can authenticate the use in a variety of ways, but the most common is using the local user logins. Local users login credentials are stored in `/etc/passwd` and their passwords are stored in `/etc/shadow`, group information is stored in `/etc/group`.